# Problems When Displaying Data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, format, jira, mozilla

So I am running jira for task management, etc.

With the current update of Google Chrome, I encountered the following bugs.
Bug Examples:
Instead of displaying [View Workflow](http://#) it displays [⚡View Workflowviewworkflow.view.title⁠](http://#). The same happens with other anchors. Instead of "**an hour ago**" I get **⚡⚡an hourcommon.date.relative.time.hour⁠ agocommon.date.relative.time.past⁠**

I tried to search for the script files responsible for displaying data and found that batch.js script file deals with the class names of the mentioned anchors.

Surprisingly enough there is no problem in internet explorer.

Any ideas what the solution or the cause at all?
Chrome version: Version 48.0.2564.109 m
Jira Version: 6.1.7

Comment: I think it is some kind of javascript vs security levels related issue. I saw this with firefox v37 back in the old days. I had to downgrade and wait for the next release, as I also haven't found the root cause... :-(

Comment: I hope, at least now v6.1.7 won't have to downgrade browsers...